# What would be the best approach to HTML5 video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm working on this site ( http://martindue.dk/esoft/ ) where I'd like to have a movie player inside the very first block. So I'm thinking I need to build something from scratch, because I'd like the video player to have no controls, and this "Play Button" should appear on top of the video, when it hasn't been started yet, and on click, the button should fade away and the video starts playing.

Is it possible to do without much code? I'm not a beast when it comes to Javascript (jQuery).

Comment: you can check [mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com/)

Comment: Yes, it's possible (just pick one of HTML 5 tutorials for video elements). Problem will arise for codecs. That said if you have to be compatible with older browsers...you'll need a fallback method (Flash?)

Comment: It doesn't sound very difficult: Just an element and an event listener.

Comment: Alright, I'll look onto mediaelementjs, it's very important that I can keep the layout as it is new, because it's a part of the visual identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 approaches to solve your problem:

- build your own video controls: you can read [here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/) for a start with jquery support
- use a free/open source player: [videojs](http://www.videojs.com) is a solid choice (back by Brightcove). In my opinion [mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com) is also a valid choice.
- use a premium player: [JW player](http://www.jwplayer.com) and [flowplayer](https://flowplayer.org/player/) are 2 great options. They will add extra features like ads support, unified API, live streaming, video analytics ...

Also even if [80% of current browsers](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/) do support playback for HTML5 video you should think about a fallback option (at minimum a "no support available" message telling the user what to do to watch your video - of course a flash fallback would be a better option)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the HTML5 specification exposes APIs the OP could use to roll their own player *without* requiring a third-party library or relying on the default browser controls.

Comment: @pwdst nicely said. Indeed in some case it can be faster/lightweight to build a player rather than taking on an external lib especially if only basic features are required.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't reccomend mediaelementjs as I have bad experience with it, especially on older IEs and Android.

I've just begun evaluating [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) and I haven't had any problems yet.