# Quicktime Embed not Cross-Browser

Tags: object, video, cross-browser, embed, quicktime

I currently have the following code for a Quicktime embed:

```
<object CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" width="564" height="346" CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
    <param name="src" value="spanishhb5.mov">
    <param name="qtsrc" value="/UserFiles/Servers/Server_3218684/Media/spanishhb5.mov">
    <param name="autoplay" value="false">
    <param name="controller" value="true">
    <embed src="spanishhb5.mov" qtsrc="/UserFiles/Servers/Server_3218684/Media/spanishhb5.mov" width="564" height="346" autoplay="false" controller="true" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/" scale="tofit"></embed>
</object>
```

This is working great in Safari and Chrome (on my Mac), but when I switch over to Windows it doesn't work in FireFox, Internet Explorer (8), or Google Chrome.

I think my embed code is incorrect or only recognized with a small percentage of browsers, can anyone help point me in the right direction so that my embed code works in the browsers I mentioned above?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001525-2-HTMLScripting):

> Using the HTML5 audio and video tags is the preferred way to include audio or video in a Webpage.

Things to consider:

- .mov files are packed with a proprietary container from Apple. They should work well for Apple devices however it could struggle on other platforms (it most of time requires the Quicktime plugin to be installed on the user device which is not always true on non-Apple devices). You better off transcoding to mp4 and webm for large device/browser coverage.
- Using HTML5 video tag with a fallback (be it Quicktime or Flash - Flash being most popular on this area because it has a larger adoption rate than Quicktime) is where the momentum is today for basic playback of video in a browser.

To get started with HTML5 video you can read [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html). I started that way :)

There are libraries out there that could solve the cross-browser complexity for you. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045584/what-would-be-the-best-approach-to-html5-video/23046224#23046224).